# Displaying information from a database in a loop

Tags: php, html, sql

On my website i currently have an events page. Each event is read and displayed using a database. for each row in the database i have created a new div like:

```
<body>
<?php

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require 'connect.php';
 $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 3;') ?>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>

    <div class="aboutUsContenttest">
        <div class="boxheader"><?php echo $row['a'] ?><br></div>
          <div class="aboutUsContentText">  <?php echo $row['b'] ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile ?>
</body>
```

this displays 3 different events.....

what i want to do is have an option to "Read More" meaning that i could click on a link which takes me to a separate page with more information about each event. how would i achieve this for say the second event? how would it know to take the information from the second row or div which has been created?

i hope this makes some sort of sense

Thank you

Comment: some of the code was chopped off

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parametr in the address:

```
$limit = isset($_GET['view_all']) ? "" : "LIMIT 3";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY timestamp DESC {$limit};");
```

Comment: the site i'm building is similar in style to this http://www.cocolocotribe.com/events-2.html?view=events  each of my events is displayed like that but from a database, i want to be able to click "read more" go to a new page and have that same datasebase information displayed from each div

Comment: you can write a function to get the events. just pass $limit parameter witch will set the LIMIT within your SQL. Function must know not to set LIMIT if it gets special value of $limit, e.g. -1

Comment: how would i take the information generated in the new Divs from the loop and have that information available on another page?

Comment: another example to help explain what i want to do would be a product page - each product is displayed in a list using the loop. if i then wanted to view more information on that product, how would the next page know how to retrieve that information

Answer (score 0):

Just have a page named the value of $row['b'] with a php file extension, and create an anchor with the href set to '$row['b'].php'

or, you could add the name of the page as a field in your database.

```
<body>
<?php

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require 'connect.php';
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 3;') ?>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>

    <div class="aboutUsContenttest">
        <div class="boxheader"><?php echo $row['a'] ?><br></div>
          <div class="aboutUsContentText">  <?php echo $row['b'] ?></div>
             <div><?php echo '<a href="./'.$row['b'].php.'">Read More</a>'?></div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile ?>
</body>
```